# QuerySelector with specified index in Javascript (like [1])

Tags: javascript, queryselector

How do I make:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("first")[1].getElementsByClassName("second")[2];
```

but with querySelector?

---

My guess would be:

```
document.querySelector(".first[1] > .second[2]");
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your original selection you're grabbing the second element with the class of `.first` and the third element with the class of `.second` that is also the child of the former. With this in mind you could use the [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo selector for both classes and count up accordingly. The only difference with this method in comparison to the JS you have now is that it doesn't use the zero-index.

```js
// document.getElementsByClassName("first")[1].getElementsByClassName("second")[2];

document.querySelector('.first:nth-of-type(2) .second:nth-of-type(3)').style = 'border: 1px solid red;'
```

```css
.first {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.first:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">Second (1)</div>
  <div class="second">Second (2)</div>
  <div class="second">Second (3)</div>
</div>

<div class="first">
  <div class="second">Second (1)</div>
  <div class="second">Second (2)</div>
  <div class="second">Second (3)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector(".first:nth-of-type(2) .second:nth-of-type(3)").style.color = "red"
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">second1</div>
  <div class="second">second2</div>
  <div class="second">second3</div>
  <div class="second">second4</div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">second1</div>
  <div class="second">second2</div>
  <div class="second">second3</div>
  <div class="second">second4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `>` operator of the `querySelector`, you could use the following syntax:

```
document.querySelector('.first:nth-child(1) .second:nth-child(2)');
```

Within this HTML code:

```js
var test = document.querySelector('.first:nth-child(1) .second:nth-child(2)').innerText;
console.log(test);
```

```html
<div class="first">

  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="second">Hello, I'm your selected div!</div>
  <div class="second"></div>

</div>

<div class="first">
</div>
```

The JS code will produce the output:

`Hello, I'm your selected div!`

Keep in mind that **CSS pseudoselectors** start counting from 1, not from 0, so to achieve the example you posted, you'd need to set `:nth-child(2)` and `:nth-child(3)`.

Also, if you have a different structure, it might as well be worth taking a look at the `:nth-of-type` selector, as the `:nth-child` will require to be the nth child of a parent, in an absolute sense. Differently, `:nth-of-type` will look for the nth (typeof) child of a parent.